# Can we one-box etymonline links in ELU/ELL/Linguistics/Lang Learning chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

For all the English Language sites, ELU, ELL, Linguistics, Language Learners (did I miss any), etymonline is a pretty heavily used resource. It provides very short definitions and longer etymologies, a very common discussion topic on all these sites.

For example, who knew that [the preposition 'down' comes from the name for a geographical feature](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=down)? Etymonline is like wikipedia for ELU chat.

A simple one-box would be an amazing feature to have and would benefit all sites.

Comment: IIRC the one-box is created server-side when you post the link. There has to be some API at etymonline that can offer the content for the one-box at a single call. At first glance it doesn't look like etymonline offers such an api. If the SE dev team has to do some html scraping I doubt they will add it.

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely SE will implement this specifically, because as @rene said, there's no official API for etymonline.

However, I have made a 'plugin' for use with my [SE Chat Custom Oneboxes userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6642/make-your-own-custom-oneboxes-for-chat). This is, by no means, an ideal solution, but it works, and could be helpful for sites such as this where SE can't implement themselves.

[image]

To use it:

1. Install a userscript manager: [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (for Chrome) or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox)
2. Install [the userscript](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/raw/master/custom-oneboxes.user.js). Clicking this link will prompt your userscript manager to ask you to install it.
3. Copy and paste the plugin (below) just above the `--------------------------------` in the middle of the script.

That's it!

Plugin:

```
customSites['etymonline.com'] = function(link, $obj) {
    var term = link.split('?')[1].split('term=')[1];
    if(term) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shu8/SE-Chat-Custom-Oneboxes/master/etymonline.css">');
        $.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent('http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=' + term) + "%22&callback=", function(d) {
            var termToDisplay = $(d).find('#dictionary dt:eq(0)').text(),
                definition = $(d).find('#dictionary dd:eq(0)').text();

            var template = "<div class='etymonline-container'>\
                              <span class='term'>[etymonline]: <a href='"+link+"'>" + termToDisplay + "</a></span><br>\
                              <span>" + definition + "</span>\
                            </div>";

            $obj.html(template);
        });
    }
};
```

Once you've installed it, you can quickly check if it works by going to [this chat link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32921577#32921577), which is a etymonline link, which will transform into a nicer-looking, more helpful onebox! :D

---

If you have any installation questions, or any design suggestions (I did this really quickly!) please do comment here.